# Is it right to say I think I'm leaving?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I was at work today and I said "I think I'm leaving" (looking at the weather because it had stopped raining) and my coworker said I should say "I'm thinking about leaving" instead.

Did I say it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I'm thinking about leaving" implies that you have not yet decided to leave.
"I think I'm leaving" implies that you have decided to leave and are about to do so. In that usage the 'thinking' is a way of softening the blow of your decision. So, for example, if you are with a group of friends in the late evening and say "I am going to bed", that sounds a bit abrupt. But if you were to say "I think I shall go to bed" it is more polite: it leaves the way open to your friends to say "No, the evening has just begun...".

Comment: So, answering the question, he didn't say it wrong, right?

Comment: It depends what he meant, but I would guess he meant what he said.